# Changing images of UIImageView in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uistackview

I have UIStackView (red). When I put in this stackView imageView with picture, this imageView becomes UIView and after that I can't change image even if I want.

I have slider, with image changes counter in my stack view, and button which should change images of my imageView.

[image: my app]

[image: my UIImageView]

Stack View contains only UIView, not UIIMAgeView. Because of that I can't change imageView image.

[image: StackView contains UIView, Not UIImageView]

[image: try to change image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the `stackView.arrangedSubviews` elements to `UIImageView`

```
@objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for case let imageView as UIImageView in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
        imageView.image = newImage
    }
}
```